# Convert String to Date in Big Query error

Tags: date, casting, google-bigquery

I have a string field that is being pulled from a table and I'm trying to cast that as a date in a view I created. I keep getting an error when trying to Cast as a date though. The format of the field looks like this:

July 19, 2020 or
August 8, 2020 etc..

I get an error that states

> "Failed to parse input string "July 19, 2020"

or one of the other dates in the data when trying to use DATE_Parse. Or I get

> "Invalid Date:August 8, 2020"

if I try to use the CAST function.

Below is my query when trying to CAST the date:

```
select
noteattributes.value.name as name_type, noteattributes.value.value as name_value, CAST(noteattributes.value.value as DATE) as DATE_TEST, order_number
from test.orders,
unnest(note_attributes) as noteattributes
where noteattributes.value.name = 'Pickup-Date'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Convert String to Date

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You should use PARSE_DATE instead of CAST as in below example

```
PARSE_DATE('%B %d, %Y', date_as_string)
```

You can test, play with this using example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'July 19, 2020' date_as_string UNION ALL
  SELECT 'August 8, 2020'
)
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%B %d, %Y', date_as_string) AS date_as_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row date_as_date     
1   2020-07-19   
2   2020-08-08
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a problem sql impala >> `UDF ERROR: String to Date parse failed. Invalid string val: "20000000"`

you have data issue. Try to do this, change your field `Date`

```
IF(length(FieldDate)!=8 OR cast(substr(trim(FieldDate),5,4) as BIGINT)=0, NULL, CAST(trim(FieldDate) AS DATE FORMAT 'yyyymmdd')) as Out_FieldDate,
```